# Hash assignment as array

Tags: perl

I'm trying to understand the piece of code below; I just cannot understand what is being done in line 15.

It seems like it is trying to initialise/assign to `%heading` but I am just not sure how that syntax works.

```
$strings = [qw(city state country language code   )];

my $file = "fname";
my $fn   = $strings;
my $c    = 0;

open( FILEH, "< ${file}.txt" ) or die( $! );

while ( <FILEH> ) {

    my %heading;
    chomp;
    $c++;

    @heading{ ( @$fn, "One" ) } = split( /[|]/ );  # Line 15

    if ( defined( $heading{"One"} ) ) {
        my $One = $heading{"One"};
    }
```

Comment: `split( /[|]/ )` is usually written as `split /\|/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called a "slice". It assigns to several keys at once:

```
@hash{ $key1, $key2 } = ($value1, $value2);
```

is a shorter and faster way of doing

```
$hash{$key1} = $value1;
$hash{$key2} = $value2;
```

`@$fn` is the same as `@{ $fn }`, i.e. array dereference.

Comment: Thanks but what about   @$fn ? Could you explain how that works ?

Comment: so In Perl string can be dereferenced as array  ?  because in code above $fn is actually a string.

Comment: @Vicky no, in line 1 the variable `$strings` is assigned with an array reference of strings, and in line 5 `$fn` is initialized with `$strings`. So it's an array ref.

Comment: @Vicky what line 15 does is it assignes the result of the `split` operation to elements in `%heading` named after every element in the array reference `$strings`, and one that's called `"One"`. It seems it's reading a CSV file that is using a pipe `|` as the delimiter. It is supposed to have at least five fields (city, state, country, language and code), but if there is a sixth field that ends up in `$heading{One}`, and then the special case in line 17ff occurs. However, line 19 does nothing as the lexical variable `$One` goes out of scope immediately because that block ends in the next line.

Comment: @choroba: Thanks again I understand that now, one last thing that I want to ask is that whenever an array is dereferenced using an array reference  like in @$fn, it never comes in a scalar context ? (to return count of array elements)

Comment: @Vicky: I don't understand. Of course, dereferencing an array ref in scalar context returns the size: `my $size = @{ [ 'a' .. 'z' ] };` sets $size to 26.

Comment: I mean  when using  @$fn in the above code , isn't it being used in scalar context ?

Comment: @Vicky: No, the list of keys enforces array context.